# How to solve the problem "error 'Vote' is defined but never used ( no-unused-vars)"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

can you help me?.I'm getting error when i will to import file Vote.And 
errors that appear like 'Vote'  is defined but never used   ( no-unused-vars).I tried to rename the Vote file and he result are nill.

```
Home.vue
import Vote from "@/components/Vote.vue";
export default {
name: "Home",
components: { Vote }
};

Vote.vue
<script> // @ is an alias to /src //import HelloWorld from "@/components/HelloWorld.vue";
export default {
name: "Vote",
components: {},
data: function(){
return{ emoticons : ['calon-1','calon-2','calon-3','calon-4'] }

  }
};
```

Comment: Where is the error coming from and which line does it complain about? Because `Vote` is clearly used in your example.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a linting notice. 
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.

To solve this you should use your `<Vote/>` component somewhere in your `Home.vue` HTML.

I am pretty sure that your linting rules want to have a component registration with a component use inside your HTML.
That means a simple import wont solve this, because a import is not a "using".
Do you work with the Vue-CLI? if yes, which lint rule set do you use?
you can disable not needed rules in your Webpack config.

And to find your `webpack.config.js` we need to know which kind of settings you did in your setup CLI process.

Check your: `package.json` file in your root directory, is there something like `esLint` except the npm dependencies in there?

if not then you can create a new file in your root called `.eslintrc.js` and inside you paste this:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  rules: {
    "no-unused-vars": "off"
  },
};
```

this will fix your problem but imho you should not disable such rules, they help you to clean code

Answer (score 0):

`Vote` is a variable(or class). you defined it as a string here. Please change

```
name: "Vote"
```

to

```
name: Vote
```